# Cortana Cannot Open Web Pages, Says: I'm sorry, I can't pull up websites here, but I can open apps

Tags: windows, windows-10, web, cortana

I am using Windows 10. When I try asking Cortana, open google.com, or open google.com with chrome, it says: I'm sorry, I can't pull up websites here, but I can open apps.

Can cortana not do this?? I am pretty sure it can, do I have to enable any settings?

Comment: Are you able to launch URLs from the run dialog?  `[Win]+r ` then `www.google.com` then `[Enter]` what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cortana is not a very sophisticated personal assistant and is heavily oriented
toward Windows.

To open a website with Cortana:

- Open Edge and go to the favorite page
- Click in the upper right hand corner the three dots `...`
- Select *More tools > Pin this page to Start*
- Close Edge
- Open Start and take note of exactly how it's named in there
- To use say "Hey Cortana open *its name*".

Comment: When click on the three dots and click more tools, there is no pin this page to start

Comment: And this will only work on that website, right.

Comment: What is your version of Edge? Can you add a screenshot of your three dots menu "More tools"? This can be repeated for as many websites as you like (once it works).

Comment: You could perhaps also try creating a desktop shortcut to the website, then right-click and do Pin to Start menu. Cortana might then pick it up.

Comment: Okay. I will do that.